# Get all data-* attributes in one element, and put them in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form, which uses fieldsets that could be seen as a page.

1 fieldset = 1 page

These fieldsets at the end will be dynamic, from the database etcetc.
I need to find a way to get all data-* attributes from the input's within the fieldsets. For validation rules. As these are also dynamic. Depending on what the customer wants.

```
<form id="msform">
        <!-- progressbar -->

        <!-- fieldsets foreach every group -->
        <fieldset>

            <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
            <!-- foreach every input that belongs to the group -->
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" data-email="true" data-required="true" />
            <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" id="pass" data-required="true" />
            <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" data-required="true" data-equalto="#pass" />
            <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
            <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
            <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
            <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
            <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />

        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
            <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
            <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
            <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
            <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
            <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <h2 class="fs-title">Terms Of Service</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
            <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
            <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
            <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
            <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

How can I loop through all inputs?
The point is to validate when the user clicks next(for next page), but still keep everything in one form.

Anyone have an idea?

http://jsfiddle.net/n55h4o7f/

Comment: If you are fine with using library, I'd say, use [Jquery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Comment: I think you are only looking for `data-*` attributes

Comment: @LearningNeverStops tried that, that plugin will validate the whole form in once while I only at that time need that page to be validated.

Comment: @ArunPJohny sorry yes, changed my post.

Comment: @user3446397 aah, yea.. correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your requirement and the html, it looks like all the rules are prefixed with `data-*` so you can use the data api

```js
$('#msfieldset form').find(':input').each(function() {
  var data = $(this).data();
  console.log('element', this.name);
  console.log(data, data)
  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    console.log(key, value)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="msform">
  <!-- progressbar -->

  <!-- fieldsets foreach every group -->
  <fieldset>

    <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
    <!-- foreach every input that belongs to the group -->
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" data-email="true" data-required="true" />
    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" id="pass" data-required="true" />
    <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" data-required="true" data-equalto="#pass" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
    <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
    <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
    <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />

  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
    <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Terms Of Service</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
    <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: FOund that this is doing what I want, helps me alot! Thanks!

 ` $('#msform > fieldset:visible').find(':input').each(function() {
          var data = $(this).data();
          console.log('element', this.name);
          console.log(data, data);
          $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            console.log(key, value)
          });
        });`

Answer (score 0):

You are already getting the current fieldset when clicking "next", just get all children inputs and validate them. Basic example:

```
error = false;
    inputs = current_fs.children('input');
    inputs.each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            alert($(this).attr('name') + ' may not be empty.');
            error = true;
        }
    });
    if(error) {
        animating = false;
        return false;
    }
```

See the ***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n55h4o7f/1/)***.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the fieldset for a particular page using:

```
var fieldset = document.querySelectorAll('#formId fieldset')[pageNumber];
```

You can then get all the form controls (inputs, selects, textareas, etc.) within the fieldset using its [*elements* collection](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#dom-fieldset-elements):

```
var controls = fieldset.elements;
```

You can then loop over the controls collection and use either the *class* or *data-* attribute to determine the type of validation, e.g. for a text input that is required and must be an integer:

```
<input name="foo" class="fv-required fv-int">
```

To get all the controls in the form, you can use the form's [*elements* collection](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#dom-form-elements).

To get all the *data-* attributes for an element you can use the [*dataset* property](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090423/dom.html#dom-dataset):

```
element.dataset
```

For older browsers use a for..in loop over the own properties and get the ones whose name matches `/^data-/`. Or you might loop over a list of all possible *data-* attributes and see which ones the element has, but that's probably not optimal.